# How to query a table with a 1-1 association on iOS using GRDB?

Tags: ios, swift, grdb

In my iOS project, I use [GRDB](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift) to manage a SQLite database. I try to query a table with a 1-1 association.

In my database, let's say I have 2 tables:

```
Selections
----------
- selectionId (primary key)
- position
- idSong (foreign key)

Songs
-----
- songId (primary key)
- name
- artist
```

Those two entities are linked with a 1-1 association, thanks to `idSong`.

Here is what I tried:

- the `Selection` entity:

```
class Selection : Record
{
    var selectionId: Int64?
    var position: Int?
    var idSong: Int64?

    static let song = hasOne(Song.self, key: "selectionId", using: ForeignKey(["songId"]))
    var song: QueryInterfaceRequest<Song> {
        request(for: Selection.song)
    }

    // ...
}
```

- the `Song` entity:

```
class Song : Record
{
    var songId: Int64?
    var name: String?
    var artist: String?

    static let selection = belongsTo(Selection.self)
    var selection: QueryInterfaceRequest<Selection> {
        request(for: Song.selection)
    }

    // ...
}
```

- a `SelectionSong` struct:

```
struct SelectionSong : FetchableRecord
{
    let selection: Selection
    let song: Song
    
    
    init(row: Row)
    {
        selection = row[Selection.databaseTableName]
        song = row[Song.databaseTableName]
    }
}
```

- here is how I created the two tables:

```
    // Selections:
    try db.create(table: Selection.databaseTableName) { table in
        
        table.autoIncrementedPrimaryKey("selectionId")
        table.column("position", .integer).notNull()
        table.column("idSong", .integer)
            .notNull()
            .indexed()
            .references(Song.databaseTableName, onDelete: .cascade)
    }

    // Songs:
    try db.create(table: Song.databaseTableName) { table in
        
        table.autoIncrementedPrimaryKey("songId")
        table.column("name", .text).notNull()
        table.column("artist", .text).notNull()
    }
```

- and here is how I try to get a list of `SelectionSong`, so I can get a list of `Selection`, and for each `Selection`, the associated `Song`:

```
    let request = Selection.including(optional: Selection.song)
    let list = try SelectionSong.fetchAll(db, request)
```

but then I get the following error: `missing scope 'song'`.

So how can I query my `Selection` table, so I can get a list of `SelectionSong` (a `Selection` with the associated `Song`)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the few errors to fix:

- in the `Selection` class:

```
class Selection : Record
{
    var selectionId: Int64?
    var position: Int?
    var idSong: Int64?

    static let song = hasOne(Song.self, using: ForeignKey(["songId"], to: ["idSong"]))
    var song: QueryInterfaceRequest<Song> {
        request(for: Selection.song)
    }

    // ...
}
```

- in the `Song` class, remove the useless code, so we get:

```
class Song : Record
{
    var songId: Int64?
    var name: String?
    var artist: String?

    // ...
}
```

- and finally, in `SelectionSong`:

```
struct SelectionSong : FetchableRecord
{
    let selection: Selection
    let song: Song
    
    
    init(row: Row)
    {
        selection = Selection(row: row)
        song = row["song"]
    }
}
```

And if you want to use a custom key instead of `"song"` in `SelectionSong`, change the following in `Selection`:

```
    static let song = hasOne(
        Song.self,
        key: "myCustomKey",
        using: ForeignKey(["songId"], to: ["idSong"]))
```